# Why am I not able to merge a migrated, closed question with an existing question?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, closed-questions, migrated-questions, merged-questions

I was trying to merge a [migrated, and already closed question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26869/add-timestamp-type-for-mysql-in-drupal-7), but the moderator menu didn't allow me to merge the questions.

[image: screenshot]

As the merge is from the viewed question to the question for which I would enter the URL, or the post ID, why isn't merging possible in this case?

When I tried from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/merge-questions the merge was done without problems.

**Update**: It happened again with another [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25476/get-always-notification-message-in-page-after-disabling-a-custom-module), which was migrated from Stack Overflow, and closed as duplicate.
I think the problem is trying to merge a migrated question with an existing question, as I don't have the same problem with questions that are not migrated. I know there have been changes to allow automatic migration rejections, but merging should be allowed, even if the question comes from another site.

Comment: You should totally drop meta and use jQuery `$('input').attr('disabled','false')`

Comment: If this is still an issue (i.e. it's still an issue on newly migrated and closed as duplicate questions), the likely solution to make it work is to first select "clear migration history". After you've done that, you will probably be able to merge the question. I haven't tested it, as I don't have an appropriate question to try it on, but the "clear migration history" selection exists in order to resolve situations like this where an action on the question is blocked because the question was migrated.